# Where is the protocol change proposal injected?

Tags: voting, governance, operation

Currently, we have two protocol change proposals [(Athens)](https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/athens-proposals-injected.html) for voting purposes. I'm searching for the operation(s) that protocol changes proposals were injected on and am curious of the contents of the operation(s).

Where can I find the operations and the block number that they were injected on?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am reading it wrong, there was one operation injecting both proposals:
https://tzscan.io/onydFJLWdGhfKNBfbnSLmqDu93j9NRimkbQm9WqLWYG8eyZUyTF

in Block 332624:  https://tzscan.io/BMVgMmYjA6zLbdGGKFme1VZ98GBPFgtBoJAigsH6578Yf3b8m5U

These are the two proposals:

A: https://tzscan.io/Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd

B: https://tzscan.io/Psd1ynUBhMZAeajwcZJAeq5NrxorM6UCU4GJqxZ7Bx2e9vUWB6z

Found it by looking at the source of the proposals (Nomadic labs I guess): 
https://tzscan.io/tz1fNdh4YftsUasbB1BWBpqDmr4sFZaPNZVL?default=vote

Comment: I looked there too but those operations you posted look like they are voting for their own proposals, it doesn't look like it's actually the protocol change proposals, at least the operations don't contain any code they are proposing. https://rpc.tezrpc.me/chains/main/blocks/BMVgMmYjA6zLbdGGKFme1VZ98GBPFgtBoJAigsH6578Yf3b8m5U

Comment: As outlined in this article “Amending Tezos:” by Jacob Arluck https://link.medium.com/Scmoic7tOU during the proposal phase "Any baker can submit a proposal as a hash of a tarball of .ml/.mli source code files." Means only the hash is broadcasted. The code can be published wherever the author wants. He then has to raise public attention to his proposal so people can review the code.